# Estimate finite-rank operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I have the the following problem. Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $(e_{j})_{j\in \mathbb{N}}$. Let $x\in [a,b]$, for all $h\in H$
$$ (Bh)(x) = \langle h,k_{x} \rangle,$$
with $k_{x}\in H$ unique and $B\colon H\rightarrow C[a,b]$ is a bounded linear operator.
I also know that
$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left\Vert (Be_{j}(x))\right\Vert_{L^{2}} <\infty.$$
Now I want to show that operator B is compact.
So I did the following:
Define an operator $B_{N}\colon H\rightarrow L^{2}$ by, note that I have set $k_{x}=e_{j}$

$$B_{N}(h)=\sum_{j=1}^{N}\langle h,e_{j} \rangle Ae_{j}\in \operatorname{span}\{Be_{1},\ldots,Be_{N}\}$$

Can I do this? Because $B(h)=<h,k_{x}>,$ so no summation this confuses me.

The last statement shows that $B_{N}$ is of finite-rank, since its range is a subspace of a  finite-dimensional space. For any $h\in H$, we have the estimate

$$ \begin{align}\|(B-B_{N})h\| &= \left\Vert \sum_{j=N+1}^{\infty} \langle h,e_{j} \rangle Be_{j}\right\Vert  \leq \sum_{j=N+1}^{\infty} |\langle h,e_{j} \rangle| \|Be_{j}\|
\\
&= \left( \sum_{j=N+1}^{\infty} |\langle h,e_{j} \rangle |^{2}\right)^{1/2} \left( \sum_{j=N+1}^{\infty} \left\Vert Be_{j}\right\Vert^{2}\right)^{1/2}
\end{align}
$$

For any $h$ with $\|h\|\leq 1,$

$$ \sum_{j=N+1}^{\infty} |\langle h,e_{j} \rangle |^{2} \leq \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |\langle h,e_{j} \rangle |^{2}=\|h\|^{2}\leq 1.$$

Note that we used Bessel's inequality. We now have,

$$ \|(B-B_{N})h\| = \left( \sum_{j=N+1}^{\infty} \left\Vert Be_{j}\right\Vert^{2}\right)^{1/2}\rightarrow 0, N\rightarrow \infty,$$

since $\sum_{j=N+1}^{\infty}\left\Vert Be_{j}\right\Vert^{2}$ is the tail of a convergent series.

Thus I conclude that $B$ is compact.

Can I do this, since $k_{x}$ is unique can I set it equal to $e_{j}$?
I am confused by the role of $h$ and $k_{x}$, which one is equal to $e_{j}$?

Comment: I'm not sure what $x$ is here. Could you clarify? Also presumably, $(Bh)x$ is a scalar, but you're taking its $L^2$ norm?

Comment: I made some edits. $x$ is in the interval $[a,b]$, $(Bh)x$ is what confuses me. It is not a scalar I think, the first statement is simply that there is a unique $k_{x}$ such that $\langle h,k_{x}\rangle=(Bh)(x)$. Maybe I have to say my self, define $(Bh)(x)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\langle h,e_{j}\rangle(Ae_{j})(x)$?